# Why doesn't this if Statement work on datgridview CellEndEdit event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` on my form that I add rows into it. And I also can edit each Cell.

And in the `dataGridView1_CellEndEdit()` I check if they are written correct, if they have spaces, I check some of the cells if they have ONLY NUMBER etc etc.

But while testing the grid I found a bug that I can't fix. If I click the cell to edit, and than I erase/remove every character on it with the Back Button or I select them and click the *Back* or *Delete* button, and when I click the *Enter* Button, it doesn't go to the `IF STATEMENT` that I have put:

```
if(CellText == "" || CellText == string.Empty || CellText == null
```

(*I put all of them to try getting it work, but none of them worked :(*   )

What should i do now ?? All the if statements that I've put for checking if there is space, if it is number or not etc... all are working... only this one not?!

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What is the `CellText` here?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the debugger or something similar to find out **what** the exact value of `CellText` is in the scenario you describe (where it is not entering your `if`).

Adjust your statement accordingly - don't try fixing it by blindly making the `if` condition more "loose".